# Docker compose attach network without IP

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose

Is it possible to attach network to a container in docker compose without ip address.

Currently the syntax accepts either list of networks like this

```
networks:
  - net1
  - net2
```

in this case ips will be assigned automatically or like this

```
networks:
  net1:
     ipv4_address: 1.1.1.1
  net2:
     ipv4_address: 1.1.1.1
```

in this case I can assign the ips manually (but this is mandatory)

However how can I leave one of the networks without ip?

Thanks

Comment: (I'd suggest using the first form you show, and ignoring the Docker-internal IP addresses altogether.  It's important to know they exist but they're unusable from outside the container in most cases, and with Docker's internal DNS system you don't need to know them inside a container either.)

Answer (score 0):

Using this syntax:

```yaml
    networks:
      net1:
      net2:
        ipv4_address: 1.1.1.1
```